# Public string doesn't want to update

Tags: c#, .net, string, methods, public

I have two forms.. Form1.cs and TwitchCommands.cs

My Form1.cs has a global variable

```
public string SkinURL { get; set;}
```

and I want that string to be the value of a textbox in TwitchCommands.cs

Here's the code in TwitchCommands.cs that should set the public string "SkinURL" in Form.cs

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSkinURL.Text == @"Skin URL")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"Please enter a URL...");
            }
            else
            {
                var _frm1 = new Form1();
                _frm1.SkinUrl = txtSkinURL.Text;
                Close();
            }
        }
```

Here's the code in Form1.cs that tries to access the string "SkinURL"

```
else if (message.Contains("!skin"))
                {
                    irc.sendChatMessage("Skin download: " + SkinUrl);
                }
```

Let's say the txtSkinURL.text = "www.google.ca" and I call the commmand in Form1.cs

It returns "Skin download: " instead of "Skin download: www.google.ca"

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because you are creating a NEW instance of Form1. An instance with its own SkinURL variable and of course that variable has not received your changes made on the first instance of Form1

Comment: How would I access the SkinURL variable then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a NEW instance of Form1. An instance with its own SkinURL variable. It is this variable that receives the text from your second form. The variable in the first instance of Form1 is not touched by your code

This could easily demonstrated if you call the Show method on the new instance

```
....
else
{
    var _frm1 = new Form1();
    _frm1.SkinUrl = txtSkinURL.Text;
    _frm1.Show();
}
...
```

In your scenario I think that you need to put your global variable inside the TwitchCommands.cs form and when you call that form you could read it back

In TwitchCommands.cs

```
public string SkinURL { get; set;}
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSkinURL.Text == @"Skin URL")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Please enter a URL...");
    }
    else
    {
        SkinURL = txtSkinURL.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

and in your Form1.cs, when you call the TwitchCommands.cs form

```
TwitchCommands twitchForm = new TwitchCommands();
twitchForm.ShowDialog();

string selectedSkin = twitchForm.SkinURL;
... and do whatever you like with the selectedSkin variable inside form1
```

Comment: Thanks. That was my error. I was doing twitchForm.Show(); and not twitchForm.ShowDialog();